# Json operations in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have MySQL database that I am reading with PHP:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}   

$sql = "SELECT Grad FROM lista";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $rows[] = $row; 
}

mysqli_close($con);

$arr = array_flip(array_map('serialize', $rows));
$lista = array_map('unserialize', array_flip($arr));
echo json_encode((object) array('lista' => array_values($lista)));
```

And from localhost I am getting this:

```
{"lista":[{"Grad":"Beograd"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad"},{"Grad":"Kragujevac"}]}
```

Is there a way to get something like this:

```
{"lista":[{"Grad":"Odaberite grad"},{"Grad":"Beograd"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad"},{"Grad":"Kragujevac"}]}
```

I would like to add `{"Grad":"Odaberite grad"}` in front of everything. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Please not that {"Grad":"Odaberite grad"} is not a part of MySQL table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding what you want after declaring `$arr` like follows:

```
$rows = array();
$rows[] = array('Grad' => 'Odaberite grad');
```

Update:

Alternatively as other answerers have pointed out you can also use `array_unshift` like follows:

```
array_unshift($rows, array('Grad' => 'Odaberite grad'));
```

Comment: Tnx. This is what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Err yeah i forgot the key name on my answer :| lmao

Comment: @RutgerKappers, it happens sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

To me there's no clear logic on how you want to sort the results, but in such case, if you want one to be very first, just add another column to your table, like `priority` and it to i.e. `0` for all rows then set it to i.e. `1` or higher for favorite row and then select with `ORDER BY priority DESC` and voila.

**EDIT** To prepend your item to result array use `array_unshift()`: http://php.net/array_unshift

Comment: This part {"Odaberite grad"..} is not in a table. I just wanted to add it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepend values to an array using

```
array_unshift($arr, "Odaberite grad");
```